# Where do we add the custom format in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, joomla3.0, custom-formatting

So I want to add some custom formats in the TinyMCE editor for Joomla. I am a novice and this might sound like a stupid question, but where is the init function where I add these custom formats. I have read through the following link http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php I do understand that I have to add my custom format in the tinymce.init function.

I have tried to find it in the site/media/editor/tinyMCE folder which does include tinyMCE.min.js and I added my custom format to it. But it was not displayed in the actual editor.

Similarly, I would like to add a template to the editor. I saved my created template in the site/media/editor/tinyMCE/template folder which looked like had all the templates. But even that did not worked :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinymce `init` function could be found under:

```
/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php
```

It depends on mode that is running but you could find it approximately at line 575.

Please note that it's a core change that may get overridden in joomla update so you have to keep a backup of this file.

Hope this helps.